# Is there a way to scan QR codes in colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a colab notebook and have been fruitlessly trying to find a way to scan a QR code that would be held up to my webcam. I have code to capture an image, if live QR code detection is a problem (I yoinked it from another notebook which is why its kind of weird):

```py
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode

def take_photo(filename='photo.jpg', quality=0.8):
  js = Javascript('''
    async function takePhoto(quality) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      const capture = document.createElement('button');
      capture.textContent = 'Capture';
      div.appendChild(capture);

      const video = document.createElement('video');
      video.style.display = 'block';
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});

      document.body.appendChild(div);
      div.appendChild(video);
      video.srcObject = stream;
      await video.play();

      // Resize the output to fit the video element.
      google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);

      // Wait for Capture to be clicked.
      await new Promise((resolve) => capture.onclick = resolve);

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
      div.remove();
      return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);
    }
    ''')
  display(js)
  data = eval_js('takePhoto({})'.format(quality))
  binary = b64decode(data.split(',')[1])
  with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(binary)
  return filename

from IPython.display import Image
try:
  filename = take_photo()
  print('Saved to {}'.format(filename))
  
  # Show the image which was just taken.
  display(Image(filename))
except Exception as err:
  # Errors will be thrown if the user does not have a webcam or if they do not
  # grant the page permission to access it.
  print(str(err))
```

I have tried things with pyzbar (followed tutorials) and many other ways, but none of them seem to work for me.

The ultimate goal is to take the data from the qr codes, and append it into lists that I would convert into a .csv (all data comes in the qr code like "name,email,phone#"). It would be great to have it work with live camera, so it just automatically does this every time it sees a QR code. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can use this pyzbar

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
decode(Image.open('pyzbar/tests/code128.png'))
```

Comment: tysm it prints this:
```[Decoded(data=b'name namer,test@email.com,123456', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=176, top=174, width=178, height=187), polygon=[Point(x=176, y=344), Point(x=345, y=361), Point(x=354, y=180), Point(x=181, y=174)])]``` I see it prints it there but how can I get the data returned? also is there a way to input a live feed instead of a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Write to install:

```
pip install pyzbar[scripts] or !pip install pyzbar[scripts]
!apt install libzbar0
```

Later import some these, but the principal is pyzbar:

```
import shutil
import os
import random
import re
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
import glob
import pyzbar.pyzbar
from PIL import Image
```

And check this:

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
```